# SOAP one server with a WSDL file for each store

Tags: java, web-services, magento, soap, wsdl

I am currently working on a Java SOAP client that consumes the SOAP Web Services from a large ecommerce provider (Magento). On that server, I want to be able to talk to multiple instances (in this case stores). Now normally, one would get the WSDL file and generate the classes with it. However, on that server, each instance has its own WSDL file that may or may not be identical in structure. What is the strategy for me as the client. Should I generate Java classes for each WSDL file? Would that give me too many packages? Are these packages permanent or temporary for a request? Should I forego creating classes and just use the harder approach: some SOAP Client (any recommendations?) along with `HttpUrlConnection`?

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this](http://www.codepetals.com/setup-your-magento-store-for-integration-with-mobile-app-or-an-erp/)

You need to create the object (http://magentohost/api/V2_soap?wsdl=1) once and this will have all the information required for the webservices and its structure as well.